# Generic List<T> class level variable

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, generics

I'm trying to create a `List<T>` where the user specifies what the data type is by selecting it from a `ComboBox` on the UI. I've managed to create an object of the `CustomEntity`, which holds the `List<T>`, but once I exit from the `Button1_Click` event handler, the `CustomEntity` will go out of scope. Is it possible to create a class level variable? I tried but had to comment it out as it caused an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomClassWithGenericList
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //The following error is created: Cannot implicitly convert type
        //CustomClassWithGenericList.CustomEntity<decimal> to
        //CustomClassWithGenericList.CustomEntity<object>


        //private CustomEntity<object> input1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cb1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper() == "DECIMAL")
            {
                input1 = new CustomEntity<decimal>();

                string[] temp = textBox1.Text.Split(',');

                foreach (string s in temp)
                {
                    decimal number;

                    if (decimal.TryParse(s, out number))
                    {
                        input1.inputValue.Add(number);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error occured.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper() == "INT")
            {
            }
            else if(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper() == "TIMESPAN")
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomEntity<T>
    {
        public List<T> inputValue; 

        public CustomEntity()
        {
            inputValue = new List<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CustomEntity<T>` won't work as the compiler has no idea what `T` is at that particular point. `CustomEntity<decimal>` should work.

Comment: @J.Steen: I don't think you're right about that.  You can have a private `List<T>` variable, instantiate it with a specified T type at run time, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It won't be visible throughout the program (only within a Form1 instantiation), but it should still work.

Comment: a suggestion would be to use a list that utilizes the object class CustomEntity<object>

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm actually pretty sure that particular declaration would receive a "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found" error.

Comment: Eh, maybe you're right.  I don't actually have an IDE in front of me right now.  I've become too dependent on IDE's.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Linqpad, man! =) (or maybe you're on a cellphone or a !Windows-machine or whatnot. In that case, never mind. =)

Comment: @J.Steen The error is "The type or namespace name "T" could not be found (are u missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of techniques could be used there. First of all you could create `Object` or [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type variable and just casting it any you want.

Also you could store your data in some state in memory (like some session or application state, or cache, stuff like that) and in such case just take it from this source.

Comment: How does declaring a private member not qualify as in memory state?

Comment: I mean some source like session state, cache and other places which available through all aplication.

Comment: @Ph0en1x give me a few mins to check out the link u posted. Thanks!

Comment: @Ph0en1x My mistake. But you should clarify that in your answer. =)

Comment: @Ph0en1x 2 secs and ill update the code with object. I still get the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'CustomClassWithGenericList.CustomEntity<decimal> ' to '......CustomEntity<object>'".

Comment: @HansRudel When declared as a CustomEntity<object>, you also need to instantiate it as a CustomEntity<object>, not CustomEntity<decimal>. Unfortunately, generics simply don't work in that way. =)

Comment: @J.Steen so at somepoint, im going to have to cast the data thats in there, to a specific type? The values which were going to be contained in this, are going to be used as parameters for a method, so id have to cast them either before i pass them to the method, or get the method to cast them inside?

Comment: @HansRudel Pretty much - but you won't know the type contained at that point, I'm assuming. I'd try to rethink the general design of this if I were you, and not *start* with trying to make it super-generic to begin with. Get it working with an "uglier" solution, then refine it with refactoring as you go along. You could also reparse (not cast) the object *if* you happen to know the type. And unfortunately I'm heading off for the evening. I wish you good luck, however, in learning. =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23815/discussion-between-hans-rudel-and-j-steen)

Comment: Ok, looks like covariance working different with generics. But object and dynamic still solve the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The commented out line uses type T, which is not a defined type. Not that you need to specify the type argument list of the generic at the point of decleration, and not anywhere else.

If you want the generic to be able to hold any object, you should simple pass the type "object" as the type argument into it.

If it can only a few different types though, creating one member variable per type might be a prefered option, depending on how you plan to use it later.

Comment: no the whole point is that i wont know the type until the button has been clicked. Yet how can i have a class level variable to hold the custom class? Thanks for your time.